# Java UDP - How to transfer files from Server to Client

Tags: java, sockets, udp

Hi and thanks in advance,

So I have a program which already creates a socket and can send strings both ways between the server and client using UDP.

However, I need to ask something before I continue with trying to send a file (specifically a text file) over my connection.

Is there a way to physically send an actual file over the connection as apposed to simply sending the files contents, or does sending it contents count as sending the files itself?

I just want to make sure on this before I continue with my program.

Thank you.

Comment: You are not sending "a file" you are sending bytes. UDP is unaware of how the payload bytes are interpreted. The question would be "what do you consider 'a file'"? Is it just its contents or do you need meta-information, too? So, just do what your requirements say. But either way: you would *at least* send the contents.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Comment: I guess you know but just to be sure: You know, you'll have to deal with lost packets and packet-order yourself, right? It will not be enough to send the file's byte content. You'll need some protocol.

Answer (score -1):

A file is not a physical object. It is more an idea of interpreting your disks magnetical (or electrical) state.

A "file" is mainly its content. There is some additional information like permissions, owner, last edit date and so on. But I assume that you don't want to send these information.

I have no idea what the specific goal is you are trying to achieve but it is safe to say, that for most applications it is perfectly fine to think of the contents of a file when saying "file".

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up :). I just wanted to make sure ;)

Comment: Please do not post comments as answers. You can tell it's a comment because you say _"I have no idea what the specific goal is you are trying to achieve"_.  This is correct, the question is off-topic, and your answer is merely a suggestion and request for clarification.  Remember, the goal here is to build a repository of high-quality questions and answers that will help MANY people in the future.  Solving the OP's problem is a secondary goal, and when the question is so vague that you cannot figure it out, you should not post an "answer", but ask for clarification.